# Access multiple captures of one capture group in substition string

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the regex `(\d)+`. 
In .Net I can access all captures of this capture group using the match.Groups[1].Captures.

Can I also access these captures in a substition string?

So for example for the input string `523`, I need to use 5, 2 and 3 in my substition string (and not just 3, which is $1).

Comment: There is a way to access them in a match evaluator, but how do you know how exactly you want to use them? What is the expected result for `523` string? A more specific (real-life) example would help.

Comment: BTW, you cannot access them via a *string* replacement pattern.

Comment: There is no specific real-life example, it's just an academic question. I though because I can access each capture/iteration of a capture group in .Net, it would be possible in a replacement pattern as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to capture the digits each in its separate capturing group then you need to actually make a separate capturing groups for every digits like this:

```
(\d)(\d)(\d)
```

**NOTE**: This does not scale very well and you could not match numbers of any other length than 3 digits. In other words, no math on either `23` or `345667`!

An good page with a long and detailed explanation why this cant be done as `(\d)+` can be found here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

So if this is indeed what you want then you need to craft your own loop that searches the string for every digit separately.

---

If you on the other hand need to capture the number and not the individual digits then you simply put the `+`sign in the wrong position. I think you should write:

```
(\d+)
```

Comment: Thanks. I though because I can access each capture in .Net, these must be some way to access the same in a substition string. Apparently not.

Comment: Dear @Coder14, if you really mean "Thanks" you should show that by casting a vote.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants to get every single digit match separately.
Perhaps this will help you then:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->

' Create a list to put the resulting matches in
Dim ResultList As StringCollection = New StringCollection()
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("(\d)")
Dim MatchResult As Match = RegexObj.Match(strName)
While MatchResult.Success
    ResultList.Add(MatchResult.Groups(1).Value)
    ' Console.WriteLine(MatchResult.Groups(1).Value)
    MatchResult = MatchResult.NextMatch()
End While
```